# Defining a Collection FS collection using Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, collectionfs, angular2-meteor

I am trying to define a collection in a angular2 - meteor app using typescript. This is what I have that doesn't work:

```
export var Images = new CollectionFS("images", {
    stores: [new FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

I get the error:

```
[web.browser] collections/pdfs.ts (1, 25): Cannot find name 'CollectionFS'.
[web.browser] collections/pdfs.ts (2, 18): Cannot find name 'FileSystem'.
```

I have also tried using the conventional CollectionFS definition:

```
export var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

The error I get then is:

```
[web.browser] collections/pdfs.ts (1, 25): Cannot find name 'FS'.
[web.browser] collections/pdfs.ts (2, 18): Cannot find name 'FS'.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Those messages are typings related, I found in google : [meteor-typescript-libs](https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs). I don't know if it is official or not, you can take a look at it.

Comment: @EricMartinez I also found that. This is where the collectionFS is defined in that package I am just unsure how to incorporate it https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs/blob/master/definitions/collectionfs.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

For atmospherejs added packages, this works.

```
declare var lodash: any;
```

Try

```
declare var CollectionFS: any;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please expound on your answer. What atmospherejs package? And can you please provide a full collectionFS collection definition.